# French "everyday" philosopher book with exercises

Tags: reference-request

I forgot the name, hence this. There is a French philosopher who has written kind of "taking philosophy back to everyday life" book(s). I cannot remember his name or the name of the book(s). Can you?

Answer (score 2):

The philosophy everyday exercises book could well be this one:

[Astonish Yourself: 101 Experiments in the Philosophy of Everyday Life](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/245233.Astonish_Yourself)
by [Roger-Pol Droit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger-Pol_Droit)